# Non-primitive default props in React.js?

Tags: javascript, properties, reactjs, default, primitive

Is it possible to specify non-primitive defaults for `props` in React, that are not shared across all instances?

Since [the result of `getDefaultProps()` is cached and reused for all instances](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values), it is not a safe place to specify non-primitive defaults.

However, components are not supposed to modify their own `props`, so e.g. setting non-primitive values on `props` in the constructor is a no-no. (In fact, `props` is immutable; `React` ensures this via [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions).)

Not sure how else to make this happen...

Comment: Why would you need these to be different per instance? Isn't that what state's for?

Comment: @rossipedia configs. E.g. `<ComponentOne margin={ { top: 10, right: 20 ...` That's a simplified example that could theoretically be broken down into primitives; another that could not is a React component that accepts a `d3.scale()` with a pre-set-up `domain` and `range`.

Comment: This is generally a non-problem because you don't mutate props. If you mutate props, this is the first of many problems. It doesn't matter if it's primitive or not if you never mutate it.

Comment: no I get that, and non-primitive props are totally fine, but I'm still failing to see the use case for non-shared default props. By definition, those would be per-instance props.

Comment: @rossipedia I'm intending these to be per-instance props. Is there a different / preferred way to specify defaults for instance props? I thought getDefaultProps was the only way to specify instance props?

Comment: I should add that I'm relatively new to React so there may be some other pattern I'm supposed to be using to specify non-primitive default `props` other than `getDefaultProps()`...

Comment: You specify the instance props when you render the component (with JSX attributes). You could also use `React.createElement` directly and pass props as the second parameter.

Comment: But props are for things that don't change, and `getDefaultProps` is for things that are shared between components (and also don't change). There really isn't a way to have non-shared default props (indeed, it doesn't really even make much sense with how React is designed).

Comment: Hm...I think I'm getting it now. `props` are immutable, so even if the default is non-primitive, if it's not mutated _it doesn't matter_ that it's shared across instances. In the case of `d3.scale()`, it's just a function that is called down the line, but does not store state, so it's ok to share. In the `margin` example, the object is treated as read-only. So I guess, then, there's nothing more to it. @rossipedia if you want to summarize that in a answer I'll accept it. Thanks for talking it through with me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props` are immutable. `getDefaultProps` is for supplying prop values to components when they aren't specified when created. `props` can be any valid javascript value, including nested objects, as long as *they don't change*.

Because `props` are immutable, default props are cached and shared between all instances of an object.

For things that change during the lifetime of a component, you want to use `state`. To specify the initial shape of your component's state, you want to use the `getInitialState()` function. `this.props` will be available in that function.